# Type-level map over list of types

Tags: scala, shapeless, type-level-computation

I have this helper function:

```
def findByType[T: ClassTag](xs: Seq[Any]) =
  xs.find(classTag[T].runtimeClass.isInstance).map(_.asInstanceOf[T])
```

which I'm currently using like this:

```
val foo = findByType[Foo](xs)
val bar = findByType[Bar](xs)
val baz = findByType[Baz](xs)
```

However, there's some duplication here; what I'd like it something like (pseudocode):

```
val List(foo, bar, baz) = List(Foo, Bar, Baz).map(t => findByType[t](xs))
```

What are my options here? I can keep it the way it is, but if there's something simple to DRY this up, I've love to hear about it.

Answer (score 8):

If you absolutely have to do this kind of thing, [Shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless) can make it both cleaner and safer:

```
import shapeless._

def findByType[T](xs: Seq[Any])(implicit t: Typeable[T]) =
  xs.flatMap(t.cast).headOption
```

Note that unlike your implementation, this one won't give wrong answers on many of the standard library's generic types:

```
scala> findByType[List[String]](Seq(List(1), List("a"), 'foo))
res3: Option[List[String]] = Some(List(a))
```

Vs.

```
scala> yourFindByType[List[String]](Seq(List(1), List("a"), 'foo))
res4: Option[List[String]] = Some(List(1))
```

(You still have to be careful, though, since this won't work on user-defined generics.)

It also lets you do neat stuff like this:

```
trait Sifter[L <: HList] extends DepFn1[Seq[Any]] {
  type Out <: HList
}

object Sifter {
  type Aux[L <: HList, Out0 <: HList] = Sifter[L] { type Out = Out0 }

  implicit def emptySized: Aux[HNil, HNil] = new Sifter[HNil] {
    type Out = HNil
    def apply(xs: Seq[Any]) = HNil
  }

  implicit def otherSized[H, T <: HList, OutT <: HList](implicit
    typeable: Typeable[H],
    sifter: Aux[T, OutT]
  ): Aux[H :: T, Seq[H] :: OutT] = new Sifter[H :: T] {
    type Out = Seq[H] :: OutT
    def apply(xs: Seq[Any]) = xs.flatMap(typeable.cast) :: sifter(xs)
  }

  def sift[L <: HList](xs: Seq[Any])(implicit sifter: Sifter[L]): sifter.Out =
    sifter(xs)
}
```

And then:

```
scala> val myStuff: Seq[Any] = List(1, List('a', 'b'), "foo", 'bar)
myStuff: Seq[Any] = List(1, List(a, b), foo, 'bar)

scala> val myInts :: myCharLists :: myStrings :: HNil =
     |   Sifter.sift[Int :: List[Char] :: String :: HNil](myStuff)
myInts: Seq[Int] = List(1)
myCharLists: Seq[List[Char]] = List(List(a, b))
myStrings: Seq[String] = List(foo)
```

Which is basically a type-safe version of what you want.

Comment: Nice; I'll have to study dependent types more deeply in order to understand the Sifter example! But other than that, this is what I was looking for (although my use case is too small to warrant 15 extra lines of complexity but I'll keep this in mind for future reference).

Answer (score 2):

```
import scala.reflect.{ClassTag, classTag}
val List(foo, bar, baz) = List(classTag[Foo], classTag[Bar], classTag[Baz]).map(ct => findByType(xs)(ct))
```

Of course, now you're losing type information - `foo`, `bar` and `baz` will all have type `Option[Any]`.

Comment: Ah good point about losing type information; I guess Travis' solution will fix that too.